# React input setting state onChange sets multiple state properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a set of inputs which I would like to tie to respective properties of the component state (since no other components in the app will depend on these inputs' values, I do not want to store them in Redux.)

I've written a function which takes the input event's value and the type of the input, and is supposed to update the relevant property in the component's state.

However, when I log state, I can see that multiple values are being updated by the same input.

Can anyone see where I'm making a mistake?

```
searchInput = (typeOfFilter, placeholder) => {
    return (
        <input
            className=""
            type="text"
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onChange={e => {
                this.updateInputValue(e, typeOfFilter);
                this.filterPlots(this.props);
            }}
        />
    );
};

updateInputValue = (evt, typeOfFilter) => {
    switch (typeOfFilter) {
        case 'nextStageFilterString':
            this.setState({ nextStageFilterString: evt.target.value });
        case 'blockNameFilterString':
            this.setState({ blockNameFilterString: evt.target.value });
        case 'growerNameFilterString':
            this.setState({ growerNameFilterString: evt.target.value });
        case 'varietyFilterString':
            this.setState({ varietyFilterString: evt.target.value });
        case 'regionFilterString':
            this.setState({ regionFilterString: evt.target.value });
        case 'ripenessFilterString':
            this.setState({ ripenessFilterString: evt.target.value });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you forgot to use `break` after setState inside `switch` case. Check **[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)** for details about `switch`.

Write it like this:

```
updateInputValue = (evt, typeOfFilter) => {
    switch (typeOfFilter) {
        case 'nextStageFilterString':
            this.setState({ nextStageFilterString: evt.target.value });
            break;
        case 'blockNameFilterString':
            this.setState({ blockNameFilterString: evt.target.value });
            break;
        case 'growerNameFilterString':
            this.setState({ growerNameFilterString: evt.target.value });
            break;
        case 'varietyFilterString':
            this.setState({ varietyFilterString: evt.target.value });
            break;
        case 'regionFilterString':
            this.setState({ regionFilterString: evt.target.value });
            break;
        case 'ripenessFilterString':
            this.setState({ ripenessFilterString: evt.target.value });
            break;
    }
};
```

But you don't need this big code to update specific state property, because you are already passing the property name to `updateInputValue` function.

Simply write it like this:

```
updateInputValue = (evt, typeOfFilter) => {
    this.setState({
        [typeOfFilter]: evt.target.value
    })
}
```

Comment: Lo and behold, it works!

I didn't think of using brackets notation for setState; I guess it's like saying state[typeOfFilter]. 

Thanks!

Comment: yes, setState is basically a function and we need to pass a object with key and value that we want to update, so we can use all the js magic inside setState :)